# Locking one table in mysql requires me to lock other tables too

Tags: mysql

I have been working on a private database package for mysql in perl and the previous person locked one table for writing in the code. But in the same function, I need to call other functions which access the database, but not the locked table. But if I don't lock all the tables accessed in the function, I am always getting an error stating:

`Table '...' was not locked with LOCK TABLES`

Can someone explain me why that is so, and how to fix it maybe?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about the database's setup? Are you using MYISAM or INNODB? Are their foreign keys for the table that was locked?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to look that up. I am not good with databases. I am using mariadb on my pc as a test environment. How can I look up those informations?

Comment: What client do you use to connect to your database when you want to look at the data?

Comment: For looking at the data I am using the MySQL Workbench, but for connecting to the database from the code I am using a mysql perl module.

Comment: Right click your table and select "alter table". Then: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-foreign-keys-tab.html

Comment: The Engine would be MyISAM.
I actually bypassed the problem by restructuring the code a bit, so I only access the table while it's protected. But I would still like to know why this problem happens, so I can get a better understanding for it.